# Last reducer tasks are taking long time to finish

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I have a cluster setup which has 8 nodes and I am parsing a 20GB text file with mapreduce. Normally, my purpose is get every line by mapper and send with a key which is one of the columns on the row of input file. When reducer gets it, it will be written to different directory based on the key value. If I give an example:
input file:

```
test;1234;A;24;49;100

test2;222;B;29;22;22

test2;0099;C;29;22;22
```

So these rows will be written like this:

```
/output/A-r-0001

/output/B-r-0001

/output/C-r-0001
```

I am using MultipleOutputs object in reducer and if I use a small file everything is ok. But when I use 20GB file, 152 mappers and 8 reducers are initializing. Everything finishes really fast on mapper side, but one reducer keeps continue. 7 of the reducers finishes max 18 minutes, but the last one takes 3 hours. 
First, I suspect the input of that reducer is bigger than the rest of them, but it is not the case. One reducer has three times more input than the slow one and that finishes in 17 minutes.

I've also tried to increase the number of reducer to 14, but this was resulted with 2 more slow reduce tasks.

I've checked lots of documentation and could no figure why this is happening. Could you guys help me with it?

**EDITED**

The problem was due to some corrupt data in my dataset. I've put some strict checks on the input data at mapper side and it is working fine now.

Thanks guys.

Comment: Is the machine running this reducer weak or unhealthy??

Comment: Can you post the counter stats for a reducer that ran quickly vs the one that ran for 3 hours

Comment: Yes the machine is fine, because it is not always happening at that node.

Answer (score 6):

I've seen that happen often when dealing with skewed data, so my best guess is that your dataset is skewed, which means your `Mapper` will emit lots of records with the same key that will go to the same reducer which will be overloaded because it has a lot of values to go through.

There is no easy solution for this and it really depends on the business logic of your job, you could maybe have a check in your `Reducer` and say if you have more than N values ignore all values after N.

I've also found some doc about [SkewReduce](https://code.google.com/p/skewreduce/) which is supposed to make it easier to manage skewed data in a Hadoop environment as described [in their paper](http://sites.computer.org/debull/A13mar/bala.pdf), but I haven't tried it myself.

Comment: Same thing is happening with me also.

Comment: Is there a way number of records that each reducer is using.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the explanation. I knew that my dataset does not have evenly distributed key value pairs. Below is from one of tests which I used 14 reducers and 152 mappers.

**Task which finished 17 minutes 27 seconds**:

FileSystemCounters

FILE_BYTES_READ         10,023,450,978

FILE_BYTES_WRITTEN  10,023,501,262

HDFS_BYTES_WRITTEN  6,771,300,416

Map-Reduce Framework

Reduce input groups 5

Combine output records  0

Reduce shuffle bytes    6,927,570,032

Reduce output records   0

Spilled Records 28,749,620

Combine input records   0

Reduce input records    19,936,319

**Task which finished 14hrs 17minutes 54 sec :**

FileSystemCounters

FILE_BYTES_READ 2,880,550,534

FILE_BYTES_WRITTEN  2,880,600,816

HDFS_BYTES_WRITTEN  2,806,219,222

Map-Reduce Framework

Reduce input groups 5

Combine output records  0

Reduce shuffle bytes    2,870,910,074

Reduce output records   0

Spilled Records 8,259,030

Combine input records   0

Reduce input records    8,259,030

The one which takes so much time has less records to go through.

In addition to this, after some time, same tasks are initializing from different nodes. I am guessing hadoop thinks that task is slow and initialize an another one. But it does not help at all.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the counters from slow running reducer and fast running reducer

task_201403261540_0006_r_000019 is running very slow and task_201403261540_0006_r_000000 had completed very fast

Its very clear that one of my reducer is getting huge number of keys. 
We need to optimize our Custom partitioner

[image]

[image]